# How do you use workshop on Civilization V?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I'm trying to use some add-ons for Civ V from the workshop. [I subscribed to some as described in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/75732/4163). When I start the game, nothing. I restarted Steam and then the game, nothing. I bet I'm suppose to use the "MODS" section, but the only one that appears is one I downloaded long ago, before workshop! Is there some special manipulation that can make it work? I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that some mods won't be delivered through Steam Workshop while others work fine. I have no idea why. In those cases I search for the mod using Google and download it, typically from [CivFanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=395).

Answer (score 1):

Some mods require the game to restart. All mods in Civ V only appear in the Mod section and must be enabled by clicking the green circular check box in the mod list.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. The asker to this question says he has already tried restarting, so it'd be nice if you could suggest an alternative.

Comment: In which case I would try David Harkness' suggestion of manual install. Look here to see if the files are there. "%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\MODS" you can try searching for your mod. Most of them are available on fan sites like CivFanatics.