# Subscribing to mods in Steam Workshop does nothing

Tags: steam, civilization-5, mods

I've had Civilization 5 for a year or so now and every time I wish to add a mod I go in and click the  "Subscribe" button and nothing happens. So if anyone has had this problem can they tell me how to fix it please.

Comment: Define "nothing happens".

Comment: When I scroll down and click on the green button with the plus and the word "subscribe" on it literally nothing happens at all. nothing tries to load, nothing changes on my screen and when I tried to launch it in a new tab, still it only created a new tab and then stopped dead. Does that help?

Comment: Update the browser you're using to subscribe, try a different browser if that fails (Steam Clients counts as a browser).

Comment: Do you mean changing from Chrome to Internet Explorer? (for example)

Comment: Yes, if updating the browser doesn't help.

Comment: See also my comment on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/75732/75 - note that after you've subscribed to a mod in steam you still need to enable it within the game.

Comment: One more thing: are you playing on PC or Mac? Civ 5 on Mac does not have mod support, which Steam does not acknowledge anywhere. Last I checked, I could subscribe to mods, and Steam would actually say it's downloading them, but there is no dialog for enabling mods in-game, and last I checked, there is not even a way to hack in partial mod support anymore, as there was early on. My understanding is that for some technical reason Aspyr couldn't make all mods function the same on Mac as on Windows, so they disabled the feature instead.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find the latest version  of your browser
2. Download it
3. Install it
4. Subscribe to mods in workshop
5. Close the game
6. Reopen the game
7. Go to mods in the menu screen
8. Check for a change